# Selenium - Get text from hidden tooltip by moving mouse horizontally

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, tooltip

I need to activate each hidden tooltip in sequence to get the price of average sale for each day as it looks on the chart at the bottom of the page: https://stockx.com/adidas-yeezy-boost-350-v2-israfil [image: ![chart]
The problem is that tooltip is hidden and the text (price and day) changes every time you move the mouse horizontally. I've tried something by this code, but it still doesn't work and I have no idea what will be working

```
driver.get('https://stockx.com/adidas-yeezy-boost-350-v2-israfil')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/button').click()

time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-login"]').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email-login"]').send_keys('abcd@gmail.com')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password-login"]').send_keys('abcd')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-login"]').click()

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="highcharts-hdwe449-0"]/svg'))
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="highcharts-w6bxh4h-109"]/svg/path')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].visibility='visible'", element)
print(driver.find_element_by_class_name('highcharts-label highcharts-tooltip-box highcharts-color-none').text())
```

I get error:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="highcharts-hdwe449-0"]/svg"}

I will be grateful for help

Comment: Is it dynamic page?

Comment: Umm there seems to be an unofficial [api](https://stockx.com/api/products/dad801b3-0fbd-4221-8351-bb54c48cdd76/chart?start_date=all&end_date=2020-08-29&intervals=100&format=highstock&currency=USD&country=IN) and also an unofficial [library](https://pypi.org/project/stockx-py-sdk/). Which would simplify lo of stuff

Comment: It is a dynamic page

Comment: dynamic pages usually use JavaScript/AJAX to read data from server and sometimes if you find url used by AJAX then you can read all data without even using Selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting `NoSuchElementException` because there is no element with xpath `//*[@id="highcharts-hdwe449-0"]/svg`.

To get the tool tip text you need to first drag your mouse over chart horizontally, then only you will text tag `<tspan>`. You can use `ActionChains` class `move_to_element_with_offset` method as below:

```
# Wait for chart to load
ele = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels ']")))
# Scroll to chart header
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//b[text()='Latest Sales']"))
#Get all elements for dates below chart
co_ordinates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels ']//*[name()='text']")
stock_Tracker = {}

# As date intervals on x-axis is for 2 days, We have to use same date element to move our moise twice
for co in co_ordinates:
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(co, 0, -35).pause(1).perform()
    try:
       key = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//*[@class='highcharts-label highcharts-tooltip-box highcharts-color-none highcharts-tooltip-header']//*[name()='tspan']").text
       value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Amount: ']//following-sibling::*").text
       stock_Tracker[key] = 'Amount: ' + value
    except:
        pass
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(co, 25, -35).pause(1).perform()
    try:
        key = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//*[@class='highcharts-label highcharts-tooltip-box highcharts-color-none highcharts-tooltip-header']//*[name()='tspan']").text
        value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Amount: ']//following-sibling::*").text
        stock_Tracker[key] = 'Amount: ' + value
    except:
        pass


print(stock_Tracker)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thanks!